# append same records in a table with only one column's data changed

Tags: sql

I've got lets say the next table

```
A B C 1

D E F 1

G H I 1
```

I want to append to this table the same records but with the 3rd column having the value 2.
like this:

```
A B C 1

D E F 1

G H I 1

A B C 2

D E F 2

G H I 2
```

Can someone help me with the sql query?

Comment: what's the SQL Script the you've tried?

Comment: THis is a bit vague. Do you wish this for a once off query? Can the value of column 4 change? Are there other entries in the table, other than col4 = 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO <table> (col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, 2 AS col4
FROM <table>
```

Comment: thanks guys! Now is there a way to run this with a single query multiple times? For example I want to have in the last column values from 1 to 7 ie having 7x3 = 21 records in the table.

Comment: `INSERT INTO <table> (col1,col2,col3,col4) SELECT x.col1,x.col2,x.col3,y.col4 FROM <table> x CROSS JOIN (SELECT 2 AS col4 UNION SELECT 3 AS col4 UNION SELECT 4 AS col4 [...]) y`

Answer (score 0):

Extended answer to your question:

> Now is there a way to run this with a single query multiple times? For example I want to have in the last column values from 1 to 7 ie having 7x3 = 21 records in the table.

T-SQL only code:

```
insert into tab col1, col2, col3, col4
select col1, col2, col3, max(col4) + 1
from tab
group col1, col2, col3
go 6
```

`6` at the end is intentionally, execute it when table is in the initial state (3 rows).